# Can ZenOSS integrate Ganglia smoothly?

Tags: nagios, zenoss, ganglia

I like Ganglia for its Gmetric function, and I like its multi-layer capability.

But Ganglia does not have healthiness check, alerting and etc. for the server monitor functionality. So it would be great to bring this two species together.

Sure, we can install Ganglia, and then install ZenOSS. But is there a plugin or something that can smoothly integrate them together? At least integration at the presentation level.

Thanks

Comment: http://community.zenoss.org/docs/DOC-5815

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I see the [nagios](/questions/tagged/nagios) tag in your question, did you consider integrating Ganglia and Nagios? If so, take a look at this:

1. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-ganglia-nagios-1/
2. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-ganglia-nagios-2/

In the Ganglia source code folder, there is a script named `check_ganglia.py` which can be used as a Nagios plugin to report on Ganglia metrics.

```
define command {
    command_name    check_ganglia
    command_line    $USER1$/check_ganglia.py -h $HOSTNAME$ -m $ARG1$ -w $ARG2$ -c $ARG3$
}
```

An example of definition to monitor CPU system:

```
define service {
    use                     generic-service
    hostgroup_name          ganglia-servers
    service_description     cpu_system
    check_command           check_ganglia!cpu_system!70!80
    max_check_attempts      5
    check_interval          5
    retry_interval          3
    check_period            24x7
    notification_interval   60
    contact_groups          admin
}
```