# How to set up alerts on Ganglia?

Tags: monitoring, cluster, ganglia, distributed-computing

How can I set up Ganglia so that I get an email if a machine in the cluster is using, for example, greater than 95% of physical RAM?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/414206/59925

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ganglia is not meant to to do alerting. It is designed to provide performance metrics for capacity planning. For alerting I would advice something like [Nagios](http://nagios.org/).
There is however a addon for ganglia that does alerting: [ganglia-alert](http://code.google.com/p/ganglia-alert/). Did not use it but it looks promising.

Comment: ganglia-alert works fine.  it's a daemon that monitors ganglia's output and can trigger emails based on thresholds or ratios going out of bounds, etc.