# How to monitor server resources?

Tags: linux, nagios, resources, monitoring, centreon

I would like to monitor the resources of my servers such as CPU, memory, disk space and many other things. I'm using Nagios + Centreon to do this, but I would like to have a historical view of the use of the resources and show them in charts to have more data to manage them through the years in a better way.

I was thinking about creating a script which would be stored on every machine and would execute every 1 minute, sending data about the resources to my application which would handle this data and store it in my database.

But I was thinking `Am I re-inventing the wheel?`
There must be some system in the market that does what I'm looking for.
I've looked into Nagios, but it doesn't handle all the information that I seek, nor does Centreon.

Does anyone know of such a system? Am I being too radical in my way of thinking?
I'm new to the infrastructure area, so sorry if this question is too naive =]

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I don't feel comfortable in using Nagios, 'cause as I said it doesn't provide all the information that I seek.

Comment: So use something else.

Comment: That's what I asking ;)

Comment: That's why you were referred to the existing question.

Comment: I don't know about inventing the wheel, but these comments are definitely turning one...

Comment: @JeffFerland =]

Comment: http://docs.pnp4nagios.org/pnp-0.6/start

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/414206/59925

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ganglia should be perfect for what you need:

http://ganglia.sourceforge.net/

Demo: http://ganglia.wikimedia.org/latest/

Comment: This looks great! I didn't know of it, thank you!